# What's the best budget gaming graphic card

Tags: graphics-cards

I want to use a budget graphic card (around 300-400 bucks) in my **gaming system**. Which you recommend?

Comment: What kind of buget; resolution, fps, quality and games do you want to play?

Comment: 100$ 100 all games

Comment: $100 gpu's are not availible at the moment. Sorry :(

Comment: Except if you get gpu's worse than a GT 1010 (worst new gpu)

Comment: I think i have 391.5 bucks

Comment: plz help me [question link](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/15652/whats-the-best-budget-gaming-graphic-card?noredirect=1#comment25774_15652) For sharing

Comment: Can i use gtx 750 Ti - 4GB?

Comment: You can, but not for all games. AFAIK, it was from before DX12 which is used in all modern games

Comment: And with a 400$ buget, things get a bit more flexible

Comment: I will use 410.5 Bucks

Comment: https://www.videocardbenchmark.net/

Comment: look at the best value chart, or at the high end chart for your price range

Comment: don't use the best value chart.  Use high end chart going from top down till you find your acceptable price range, and then you will have to internet around finding it somewhat at that price.  But an RTX3060ti 8gb (significantly *better* than non ti) shows up at bestbuy.com for for $399 as of this date/time.  Otherwise RTX3060 12gb out of stock at newegg for as low as $330; newegg shows all as out of stock

Answer (score 0):

If the 400$ buget is for GPU only, you can get a 1660 ti for €380 (about $400) or even better, a 1660 for €290 (about $320) (where I live). This won't give features like RTX or DLSS, but it will play almost all games.

Comment: Thanks, but I need RTX series. Bcaz I want to play 4K videos and gaming

Comment: If you do light games, no. You can even do 4K minecraft on my RX 570 (slower than GTX 1660)